# Plotting shapefiles in muliple panels in a single plot

Tags: r, plot, r-sp

I have some shape files saved in my R data. I first execute the following

`library(sp)`

and then run the following code:

```
pdf("OurMaps.pdf", width=11, height=8.5)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))

spplot(sh1998, zcol="lulc.1", col.regions=colorcode, col="transparent")
spplot(sh1999, zcol="lulc.1", col.regions=colorcode, col="transparent")
spplot(sh2002, zcol="lulc.1", col.regions=colorcode, col="transparent")
spplot(sh2003, zcol="lulc.1", col.regions=colorcode, col="transparent")
spplot(sh2009, zcol="lulc.1", col.regions=colorcode, col="transparent")
spplot(sh2014, zcol="lulc.1", col.regions=colorcode, col="transparent")

dev.off()
```

All I want from this code is to have a PDF file where multiple shape files would be plotted in multiple panels. However, this code is giving no outputs. What is wrong in the code?

Comment: What does it do without indicating the width and height? just pdf("OurMaps.pdf")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`par(mfrow=c(2,3))` can only be used for the base graphics system. 
The `sp` function `spplot()` uses the `lattice` graphics system, which makes use of the `grid` graphics engine. This is a low-level graphics system for R. Both packages are part of the base R distribution.

You cannot see the output because `lattice` functions return an object of class `trellis`, which need an explicit print statement `print(spplot(...))` (in scripts).
See [R FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f): Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?

> The most likely reason is that you forgot to tell R to display the
>   graph. Lattice functions such as xyplot() create a graph object, but
>   do not display it (the same is true of ggplot2 graphics, and Trellis
>   graphics in S-PLUS). The print() method for the graph object produces
>   the actual display. When you use these functions interactively at the
>   command line, the result is automatically printed, but in source() or
>   inside your own functions you will need an explicit print() statement.

The arrange multiple plots you can use `grid.arrange()` from the `gridExtra` package:

```
library("gridExtra")
library("lattice")

p <- xyplot(1~1)
grid.arrange(p, p, p, p, p, p, ncol=2, nrow=3)
```

[image: grid.arrange example]